# Is the set of zeros of $f(x)=x^2\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ is connected over $[0,\frac{2}{\pi}]$?

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness

Let $f : \left[0,\frac{2}{\pi}\right] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=x^2\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ for $x\neq 0$.

This function is continuous on $\left[0,\frac{2}{\pi}\right]$ so the set of its zeros i.e.

$$
Z=\left\{x \in \left[0,\frac{2}{\pi}\right] : f(x)=0\right\}
$$

is compact (closed and bounded).

Is $Z$ a connected set?

Please show the connectedness if it is connected and provide counterexample if it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to elucidate @suchan's answer

A space $X$ is connected if and only if the only subsets of $X$ which are both open and closed (clopen sets) are $X$ and the empty set.

And a subspace topology on $Y \subset X$ is defined by: $U \subset Y$ is open (or closed) if and only if $U = Y \cap V$, where $V$ is an open (or closed ) set in $X$.

With this, note that $$Z = \{0\}\cup\left\{\frac{2}{(2n+1)\pi} : n \geq 0\right\} \subset \mathbb{R}$$

Then look at $\left\{\frac{2}{3\pi}\right\} \subset Z$
$$\left\{\frac{2}{3\pi}\right\}=Z \cap \left\{\frac{2}{3\pi}\right\}, \text{ where as we know }\left\{\frac{2}{3\pi}\right\} \text{ is closed in }\mathbb{R};\text{  and}\\ \left\{\frac{2}{3\pi}\right\}=Z \cap \left(\frac{2}{5\pi},\frac{2}{\pi}\right), \text{ where as we know }\left(\frac{2}{5\pi},\frac{2}{\pi}\right) \text{ is open in }\mathbb{R}$$

Therefore $\left\{\frac{2}{3\pi}\right\} \subset Z$ is a clopen set, and hence $Z$ is not connected.

---

A slightly different approach

We'll first show that $A = Z \setminus \left\{\frac{2}{3\pi}\right\}$ is open in $Z$. Choose $y \in A$ and we set $\delta = \left|y - \frac{2}{3\pi}\right|$, then since $\frac{2}{3\pi} \notin B(y,\delta) \implies B(y,\delta) \subset A$, hence $A$ is open in $Z$

Take $a=\frac{2}{3\pi} \in Z$, then $B_Z(a,\epsilon)=\{x \in Z : |x-a|<\epsilon\}$. Taking $\epsilon=1/2$, you'll see that $$B=B_Z\left(\frac{2}{3\pi},\frac{1}{2}\right)=\left\{\frac{2}{3\pi}\right\}$$
Therefore, $B$ is open in $Z$.

Now, you can write $Z = A \sqcup B$, so $Z$ is not connected.

Comment: Can you explain why $\{2/3\pi\}$ is open, using the fact that interval is open?

Comment: That's the definition of subspace toplogy, you can find proofs here
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Topological_Subspace_is_Topological_Space; and
https://mathstrek.blog/2013/01/25/topology-subspaces/

Comment: What is your talking about is beyond my knowledge. That is a homework problem and I am taking real analysis course and I should show it using that knowledge. Can you help me?

Comment: Okay, do you understand what an open ball is?

Comment: Yes. I do know.

Comment: Check addendum to the answer

Answer (score 2):

I think the point $\frac{2}{3\pi}$ is both open and closed in $Z$, so $Z$ is not connected.

Comment: Notice that points the metric of the domain is $|\cdot|$ and the cannot be open and closed. Also, being open or closedness has nothing to do with connectedness.

Comment: Being open and closed has a lot to do with connectedness given that one of the definition of it is that a space $X$ is connected if and only if the only closed and open sets are $X$ and $\emptyset$

Comment: If $\mathbb{R}$ has usual topology then $\{2/3 \pi\} = Z \cap \{2/3 \pi\}$ and $\{2/3 \pi\} = Z \cap (2/5\pi, 2/\pi)$. Therefore $\{2/3 \pi\}$ is a clopen set

Comment: @NaweedSeldon I think you meant $2/((2n+1)\pi)$. Also I think $Z$ is technically not discrete here (though $Z - 0$ is).

Comment: @Naweed Seldon: I am not getting $\{2/3\pi\}$ is clopen? Can you explain it more?